# for loop reverse iteration to calculate back numbers

Tags: plsql

I am Working in a Plsql Program where i am calculating a running balance using for loop. when the loop ends running balance on last row is negative or positive , so i want to adjust the remaining balance to upper rows till it become 0 as shown in below example

```
1 1362  16802
2 1362  15440
3 1362  14078
4 14125 -47
```

from above number `-47` is remaining running balance it may be in `47` as positive. what i want that always remaining balance should be 0 if it is negative or positive it should adjusted to upper row. like

```
1 1362     16802
2 1362     15440
3 1362+47  14078
4 14125    0
```

**Another Example** when 47 is positive number.

```
1 1362  16802
2 1362  15440
3 1362  14078
4 14125  47
```

it will be

```
1 1362     16802
2 1362     15440
3 1362-47  14078
4 14125    0
```

Here is my code which too simple to calculate running balance

```
FOR j IN 1 .. l_installment_cnt LOOP 

          IF l_bal_flg = 'Y' THEN          
            l_curr_bal :=  l_calcaulatedbalance - l_install_amt;
            l_bal_flg  := 'N'; 
          ELSE
            l_curr_bal := l_curr_bal - l_install_amt;
          END IF;
         l_install_seq := l_install_seq+1;
END LOOP;
```

**Note**

Remaining balance `-47` or `47` may be more greater than the value of previous row, so it should be adjusted to previous rows till it become 0 for example

```
    1 1362   16802
    2 1362    15440
    3 1362    14078
    4 14125   -1447

it should be like

  1  1362       16802
  2  1362+85    15440
  3  1362+1362  14078
  4  14125      0
```

Comment: In the context of a database question there should be a third column which provides the order of the transactions.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Is the data you're working with in a table? If so, what determines the opening balance? (i.e., in your example, where does the `16802` come from?). Also, is this purely a learning exercise, or is this something you need to do for production code? (I ask, because if it's the latter, and your data is in a table, analytic functions will be your friend for this purpose!)

Comment: `16802` is opening balance stored in a table

Comment: @Sami and your other items are stored in another table?

Comment: yup al is stored in table i just show you the piece of values to understand the logic

Comment: Please edit your question to show the tables involved along with the sample data in them. Also, what is the logic for spreading the difference between the other rows?

Comment: @Boneist The Same Values are in Tables as show in question , Logic is to adjust the remaining Running balance to upper rows with Positive difference so remaining balance should be zero

Comment: It's still not clear. Please update your question to include your tables with sample data. Re. the logic, please explain more. For example, why are you not adding 1447 to the 14125 row in your last example? Why is 1447 split across two rows? What is the logic that decides which rows should get updated?

Comment: the Amount on last row should be same This Is Required, We can Start From 2nd Last Row. If i subtract 1447 from 2nd last row 1362 then it will be again a negative value -85 that why i need to split till it become 0

Comment: So, which is the running total that you're calculating Do you already have the values in the second column or is that what you're trying to generate? (This is why I wanted you to add your tables and their data to your question; it saves sooooo much time than asking for little crumbs of information).

Comment: Actually table has lot of columns and data so the question will be more complex.
First column is Just sequence Second Column is Installment Amount and Thirs is Running Balance and Running Balance starts from a value in Table as mentioned in variable `l_calcaulatedbalance `

Comment: @Boneist Please see my New question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423826/iterate-back-to-adjust-the-calculated-values-in-for-loop